# Keep playing Video on configuration change in a Fragment

Tags: android, orientation, fragment, android-videoview

I have a fragment that contains a VideoView and I want it to keep playing when orientation changes.

I've been searching for similar cases but I don't know the best way to proceed.

If I "setRetainInstance(true)" in the fragment's onCreate method it seems not to be enough

Can anybody give me a little help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding onConfigurationChanged in the fragment, leaving it blank:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);        

}
```

Works for a normal activity so should work fine in a fragment. You might need to override it in the parent activity as well.

**Edit:**

Forgot to say, you need to add the following tag to the activity's manifest.

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Comment: I've tried to override onConfigurationChanged in both the fragment and in its parent activity and they're not running (I put a Toast in both methods and it's never shown). Is there any way to do it without override onConfigurationChanges???? Thanks again

Comment: Edited my comment with the tag you need to add to the manifest to get onConfigurationChanged to be called.